# Why do I get a MemoryError when building my project on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to upload my api(which uses some large dependcies) to google app engine, but it fails in the build stage because of a memory error or something.

Error message:

```
Step #1 - "builder": MemoryError
Step #1 - "builder":     msg += message_body
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 890, in _send_output
Step #1 - "builder":     self._send_output(message_body)
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1065, in endheaders
Step #1 - "builder":     self.endheaders(body)
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1109, in _send_request
Step #1 - "builder":     self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1069, in request
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1320, in _conn_request
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1399, in _request
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1659, in request
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/containerregistry/transport/transport_pool_.py", line 62, in request
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/containerregistry/client/v2_2/docker_http_.py", line 354, in Request
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/containerregistry/client/v2_2/docker_session_.py", line 167, in _patch_upload
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/containerregistry/client/v2_2/docker_session_.py", line 201, in _put_blob
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/containerregistry/client/v2_2/docker_session_.py", line 275, in _upload_one
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 55, in run
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 398, in result
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/containerregistry/client/v2_2/docker_session_.py", line 314, in upload
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/common/cache.py", line 212, in Set
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/python/layer_builder.py", line 56, in BuildLayer
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/python/layer_builder.py", line 163, in _build_pkg
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 55, in run
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 398, in result
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/python/layer_builder.py", line 144, in BuildLayer
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/python/builder.py", line 114, in Build
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__.py", line 54, in main
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__.py", line 65, in <module>
Step #1 - "builder":     exec code in run_globals
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
Step #1 - "builder":     "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
Step #1 - "builder": Traceback (most recent call last):
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     full build took 213 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     build process for FTL image took 213 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     uploading_all_package_layers took 75 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     uploading_python_pkg_layer took 2 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": ERROR    Error during upload of: eu.gcr.io/sorcely/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d/python-cache:1fe79d2959d02f3da1ba4ba89bfb27027a5deb71e0ad70b6f848f893ddb9bd94
```

I've tried to change the amount of ram in my app.yaml file and just make minor changes to the code.
Hope you can help me
- Marius

Ps. I tried hosting the flask example project which worked fine

Comment: What seems to be failing here is Cloud Build before deploying to App Engine. The default [timeout](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#timeout_2) is 10mins which may not be enough for you. Could you try running `gcloud config set app/cloud_build_timeout VALUE` with a value > 600s? Here you have the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set#cloud_build_timeout).

Comment: @bhito, thanks, but when I look at the Cloud Build it only took 3:46 seconds. Do you maybe have another idea for a solution?

Comment: The Build running in the background before deploying to App Engine can't be modified, therefore you may have to work around this. The idea then would be to containerize your app and Build it using Cloud Build directly (you can specify the setting to use more memory there) and then deploy to app engine using that [image](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy#--image-url)`gcloud app deploy --image-url=$PATH_TO_DOCKERFILE` or use Cloud Run to run the same image. This is why initially adding more ram to your app.yaml didn't work.

Comment: These are the steps to [deploy to Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy#python) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds#machinetype) you have more information about Cloud Build machine types that are supported.

Comment: @bhitom, So I've to create a container which I should deploy to Google Run, then I should deploy the container (in the cloud) to my app engine?

Comment: You will have to create a container which you can run either in App Engine or Cloud Run, sorry if my previous comment wasn't that clear. To do it in app engine you can use the following command after the image has been built with Cloud Build:
`gcloud app deploy --image-url=$PATH_TO_IMAGE`
Cloud Run was just another alternative as it allows the usage of custom containers.

Comment: Thanks! I willl try that

Comment: No problem! Let me know if that solved your issue so I can add it as an answer instead :)

Comment: @bhito, sorry for not responding, I was in school. But I'm having some trouble creating a image using Docker since i am using a normal windows OS and it only supports windows enterprise or windows server. But I think that google actaully made an image my code, can I just use that?

Comment: I don't think this image will work, it's probably from the previous deployment you did with the Flask sample that was working correctly. You can use the Cloud Shell to containerize your app as the VM is UNIX based and you can use Docker. If you upload your files to a Storage Bucket and download them or even manually uploading them to the Shell.

Comment: @bhito, thanks so much for the help It really helped me out. I'm now facing a new error... Maybe you can help me out with this as well?

Comment: Sure! Will be glad to help. Although I think that if the initial question is answered we should move towards creating another question in Stackoverflow and posting an answer in that one, so other people seeing this thread won't see it confusing. I will post my initial comment as an answer here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Build running in the background before deploying to App Engine can't be modified, therefore you have to work around this. The idea then would be to containerize your app and build it using Cloud Build directly (you can specify the [machine](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds#machinetype) that will be using during the build) and then deploy to app engine using that image:

`gcloud app deploy --image-url=$PATH_TO_DOCKERFILE`

You can even use [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy#python) to run the same image.

Adding more ram to your `app.yaml` as you were trying to do initially won't work as `app.yaml` specifies the resources that your App Engine will have when your app is running, and the error is occurring when the application is trying to be built, hence it's Cloud Build not having enough memory for your app.